# How to handle events in extended classes?

Tags: .net, inheritance, event-programming, vb.net

When one extends a class, how is the proper way of setting code to be executed upon some event of the base class?

Should one handle the base class event this way:

```
Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Private Sub MyBase_MyEvent(sender as object, e as eventargs) Handles MyBase.MyEvent
        ' do stuff here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or should one override the event caller sub?

```
Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMyEvent(e as EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMyEvent(e)
        ' do stuff here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I believe this would be better for StackOverflow, as it's a problem tightly tied to a specific language.

Comment: I see. Do you think I should delete the post?

Comment: It's just my personal input at the moment, perhaps someone else will have a different opinion. You can leave it here for now, I suppose.

Comment: @DavidPacker when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are fine and common.  The big difference: with option 1, you can't necessarily tell what order the handlers are fired in, while with the second option, you can decide whether `MyBase.OnMyEvent` is called before or after your overridden implementation.